# Content Delivery Network(CDN) performance and limitation

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, cdn

I have a few questions about CDN.

1. In case my site is hosted on a server which located at US region and most of the visitors are from Asia Pacific. If I have used a CDN service that have servers in both US and Asia Pacific region, is it means that those visitors will connect to the Asia-Pacific server in a and visit my site in a high speed ?
2. Hence, if my site including some MySQL operation such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT..etc and some input parameters which have to be handled by PHP such as $_GET[], will CDN still apply and increase the connection speed ?
3. If the CDN service already including SSL protection. Is it means that I do not have to purchase an additional SSL certificate from my hosting provider ?
4. If I have updated some files in my original server, will the CDN update at the same time or it have to take a long time to refresh ?

Hoping that my question is clear enough, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, users will connect to a copy close to them, which is more or less the whole point.
2. No, the CDN will not handle your SQL queries. The CDN just holds a cached copy of some file, it does not (typically) execute any SQL. You'll have to be very selective and careful what you let the CDN cache and which pages must not be cached and handled by your server itself.
3. You'll still have to purchase a certificate for your own domain, unless you want to serve *everything* through the CDN's domains (like `kaswflqfleifnf.cdn.example.com`).
4. It will take time to refresh. That's the point of a *cache*. You're trading speed vs. potentially outdated data. How and when to correctly invalidate a cache is a topic whole books can be written about.

Comment: Even if your app is very interactive and the actual PHP pages themselves can hardly be cached, it still makes a ton of sense to distribute all **static assets** via a CDN; i.e. images, CSS files, Javascript files etc. This will take a ton of load of your server just by itself and can improve the perceived performance a lot.